# jhipster : No jhipster generation support with filtering entities on the angular client-side?

Tags: typescript, filter, jhipster, entities

Here is my attempt to solve the problem based on the work of others,
but it does not work because the transfer to VkaResource leads to VkaCriteria with all fields are null:

Excerpt from VkaResource:

```
 /**
 * GET  /vkas : get all the vkas.
 *
 * @param pageable the pagination information
 * @param criteria the criterias which the requested entities should match
 * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and the list of vkas in body
 */
@GetMapping("/vkas")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<List<VkaDTO>> getAllVkas(VkaCriteria criteria, Pageable pageable) {
    log.debug("REST request to get Vkas by criteria: {}", criteria);
    Page<VkaDTO> page = vkaQueryService.findByCriteria(criteria, pageable);
    HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page, "/api/vkas");
    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(page.getContent());
}
```

Here is the Angular code from vka.Component.ts:

```
       this.criteria = {
        mkt1: null,
        vnr: null,
        wirkungGueltigAb: null,
        wirkungGueltigBis: null,
        areSet() {
            return this.mkt1 != null || this.vnr != null || this.wirkungGueltigAb != null || this.wirkungGueltigBis != null;
        },
        clear() {
            this.mkt1 = null;
            this.vnr = null;
            this.wirkungDatAb = null;
            this.wirkungDatBis = null;
        }
    };
 }
    loadAll() {
     const criteria = [];

    if (this.criteria.areSet()) {
        if (this.criteria.mkt1 != null && this.criteria.mkt1 !== '') {
            criteria.push({key: 'mkt1.equals', value: this.criteria.mkt1});
        }
        if (this.criteria.vnr != null && this.criteria.vnr >= 0) {
            criteria.push({key: 'vnr.equals', value: this.criteria.vnr});
        }
       if (this.criteria.wirkungGueltigAb != null && this.criteria.wirkungGueltigAb >= 0) {
            criteria.push({key: 'wirkungGueltigAb.equals', value: this.criteria.wirkungGueltigAb});
        }
       if (this.criteria.wirkungGueltigBis != null && this.criteria.wirkungGueltigBis >= 0) {
            criteria.push({key: 'wirkungGueltigBis.equals', value: this.criteria.wirkungGueltigBis});
        }
    }
        this.vkaService
        .query({
            criteria,
            page: this.page - 1,
            size: this.itemsPerPage,
            sort: this.sort()
        })
        .subscribe(
            (res: HttpResponse<IVkaVka[]>) => this.paginateVkas(res.body, res.headers),
            (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
        );
}
```

Here is the code from request-util.ts

```
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

export const createRequestOption = (req?: any): HttpParams => {
    let options: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
    if (req) {
        Object.keys(req).forEach(key => {
            if (key !== 'sort') {
                options = options.set(key, req[key]);
            }
        });
        if (req.sort) {
            req.sort.forEach(val => {
                options = options.append('sort', val);
            });
        }
    }
    return options;
};
```

So, what is wrong?